# Intent.putExtra fails to pass data to new activity but Bundle.putString works fine each time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I have a peculiar issue.

From my main activity, I put a string into an intent and pass it to an activity , the screen remains blank. However, if i press back button and open the same activity it loads fine.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ListingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("rss-url",section.get(position).RssUrl);
                   startActivity(intent,bundle);
            }
    });
```

However, if instead of `intent.putExtra`, if I put the **same** URL into the bundle and pass that to the same activity, everything works and the list shows up as expected.

```
  bundle.putString("rss-url",section.get(position).RssUrl);
  startActivity(intent,bundle);
```

This is greatly puzzling me. Why would the list on the started activity load all OK when either loaded a second time OR when the screen is rotated.

While I have fixed my problem by using a bundle , I'd really like to find out why intent.putextra isn't working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While passing extras through intent.putExtra there is no need to pass bundle in startActivity() as follows :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ListingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("rss-url",section.get(position).RssUrl);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
```